# Add a dot to a mysql regex

Tags: mysql, regex, version

I have the following mysql regex:

```sql
REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}'
```

Which catches `-v01` and `-v1` and `-v03` and `-v97`, I want to add a dot `.` at the end of it:
`-v01.` and `-v1.` and `-v03.` and `-v97.`
so that it only catches version number followed by the dot.

I tried `\.` but that did not seem to work - even though it should.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to use double backslash: `REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}\\.'`

Comment: Or...  REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}[.]'

Comment: Are you asking about searching?  Or replacing?  What version of MySQL?  (8.0 changed some things, such as the doubling of backslash).

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT '-v01' val UNION ALL
  SELECT '-v12' UNION ALL
  SELECT '-v97' UNION ALL
  SELECT '-x12' UNION ALL
  SELECT '-v01.' UNION ALL
  SELECT '-v12.' UNION ALL
  SELECT '-v97.'
)
SELECT val, val REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}\\.?' FROM cte
```

| val | val REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}\.?' |
| --- | --- |
| -v01 | 1 |
| -v12 | 1 |
| -v97 | 1 |
| -x12 | 0 |
| -v01. | 1 |
| -v12. | 1 |
| -v97. | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TSNFa_qu)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this regex :

```
REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}\\.+?'

\\.+ will make sure at least one "." after 2 digits to be exist
```

This working for mysql 8.

on older mysql you can't use +? and *? It throw `repetition-operator operand invalid`

Comment: Sorry, I tried it and it throws an error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Comment: Final "zero or one" repetition operator `?` have no operand to repeat.

Comment: Yes @NicolaasThiemenFrancken did some research found that its working on mysql 8 but not on the older ones. I have added a separate answer for older versions, can you try it

Answer (score 1):

```
 I think there are two solutions, maybe more
```

The First is,

```
  Here is the code 
 "REGEXP_REPLACE(a,'(-v)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)','\1\2.')

 With backreferences \1\2 or $1$2
```

The Second is,

```
SELECT obs, REGEXP_REPLACE (obs, '$', '.') AS RESULT
FROM (SELECT 'asda -v01' AS obs FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'aaaa -v12' AS obs FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123 -v97' AS obs FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'v42 -x12' AS obs FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-v01' AS obs FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-v12' AS obs FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-v97' AS obs FROM DUAL)
```

The first code [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AWI786/1)

The second code [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5Za7JY/1)

Comment: I am not really sure what this all means.

Comment: May I ask what exactly you don't understand? If I know I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution for all mysql versions.

```
REGEXP '-v[0-9]{1,2}\\.{1,}?'

\\.{1,} instead of \\.+ will work fine with no *repetition-operator operand invalid* error.
It will make sure at least one "." after 2 digits to be exist
```

Seems you are working with an older version of mysql.